# Possible to bind javadoc parameter descr to super method's javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

There are cases that I use some method in the base class with the general usage (such as database CRUD methods), which I then better sort in the controlled which extends that base class.

Sometimes, I need to write `javadoc` for the method in controller so that I don't have to jump back to the super methods to check what is the purpose of some parameters. In such cases, I open the javadoc of the super method, copy the description and paste it into my controller method.

Now, doing it for a small amount of messages is OK, but now I am trying to make comments for the complete project and such copy/paste takes time.

Is there a way I can automatically put the parameter description from the original method's javadoc?

For example,

```
/**
 * A description of the controller method. Blah blah
 *
 * @param param1  My description
 * @param param2  My description
 * @param param3  A description copied from super method
 */
public void controllerMethod(Object param1, Object param2, Object param3) {
    //method's body...
}
```

So instead of pasting the description for the `param3`, is there a way I bind the original description with this parameter's javadoc? This way, it would not only be faster, but I don't have to change the description if it's ever updated in the super method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit the javadoc in some cases:

```
/** 
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
```

Eclipse and Co should still find the javadoc.

However: Clear names for the parameters could avoid the problem, I think.